# Passing attributes in test url - Rspec / Addressable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, addressable-gem

From a View file I pass attributes in a url:

`%= link_to piece_path(@current_piece, file: file, rank: rank), method: :patch do %>`

this gives urls like `http://localhost:3030/pieces/%23?file=8&rank=8`

I need to extract the value of file and rank from this url, to update the database fields (coordinates of a chess piece after a move).

In Controller I'm trying to use the Addressable gem:

```
def update
    (some code)
    current_piece.update_attributes(piece_params)
    (more code)
end

private

def piece_params
    uri = Addressable::URI.parse(request.original_url)
    file = uri.query_values.first    ## I don't know if "first" 
    rank = uri.query_values.last     ## and "last" methods will work
    params.require(:piece).permit({:file => file, :rank => rank})
end
```

When I inspect `uri` I get: `#<Addressable::URI:0x3fa7f21cc01c URI:http://test.host/pieces/2>`

There is **no hash of attributes trailing the url**. Thus `uri.query_values` returns `nil`. I don't know **how to mirror such thing in the test**.

The error message:

```
1) PiecesController pieces#update should update the file and rank of the chess piece when moved
     Failure/Error: file = uri.query_values.first

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass
```

In Controller_spec:

```
describe "pieces#update" do
    it "should update the file and rank of the chess piece when moved" do
      piece = FactoryGirl.create(:piece)
      sign_in piece.user
      patch :update, params: { id: piece.id, piece: { file: 3, rank: 3}}
      piece.reload
      expect(piece.file).to eq 3
      expect(piece.rank).to eq 3
   end
```

I can't check if the logic works from the localhost browser (I don't have pieces objects at the moment so I run into errors). Also working on that.

My question regards the test; however if there are suggestions to extract the attributes from the url in different ways I'm all ears!

Comment: You need to remove the quotes around `'@current_piece'` as your passing the literal string `'@current_piece'` - not the value of the instance variable.

Comment: Good catch! Actually I don't have the quotes on the actual view file but pasted this from the wrong one (where I use this as placeholder to dodge the routing error due to not having pieces objects and thus nil id)

Comment: I edited my question to correct this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`button_to` with nested attributes works; in the view file:

```
<%= button_to piece_path(@current_piece), method: :patch, params: {piece: {file: file, rank: rank}} do %>
```

And keep it simple in the controller:

```
def piece_params
  params.require(:piece).permit(:rank, :file)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to manually parse the request URI to get query params in Rails.

Rails is built on top of the Rack CGI interface which parses the request URI and request body and provides the parameters as the params hash.

For example if you have:

```
resources :things

class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    puts params.inspect
  end
end
```

Requesting `/things?foo=1&bar=2` would output something like:

```
{
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  action: "index",
  controller: "things"
}
```

`link_to method: :patch` uses JQuery UJS to let you use a `<a>` element to send requests with other methods than GET. It does this by attaching a javascript handler that creates a form and sends it to the URI in the HREF attribute.

However unlike "normal forms" in rails the params are not nested:

```
<%= link_to piece_path(@current_piece, file: file, rank: rank), method: :patch do %>
```

Will give the following params hash:

```
{
  file: 1,
  rank: 2
}
```

Not

```
{
  piece: {
    file: 1,
    rank: 2
  } 
}
```

If you want nested keys you would have to provide the params as:

```
<%= link_to piece_path(@current_piece, "piece[file]" => file, "piece[rank]" => rank), method: :patch do %>
```

Comment: You can also use `button_to` to create a discrete form element instead of a link. This lets you pass params in the request body instead of the query string.

Comment: Thank you this helped me understand how the request body works. In the end  `button_to` works for me, I'll post the solution now.

Answer (score 0):

If your URL is `http://localhost:3030/pieces/%23?file=8&rank=8` you should be able to do:

```
def piece_params
    params.require(:piece).permit(:rank, :file)
end
```

and then access them in your action via `params[:rank]` and `params[:file]`
I usually use `params[:file].present?` to make sure that the params are there before I try to assign the value. Something like this should work:

```
p = {}
if params[:rank].present?
  p[:rank] = params[:rank]
end
if params[:file].present?
  p[:file] = params[:file]
end
current_piece.update_attributes(p)
```

FWIW, you probably shouldn't use the URL string to pass params to a `PATCH/PUT` request. You might consider passing them via a form or something.

Comment: Thank you it helped knowing I should be able to do this with the simpler `piece_params` definition; and that I could pass those params in a different way than through the url. For the purpose of the project I'm working on security isn't an issue but it's definitely worth knowing about!